# Invalid format error when inserting data in the database (C# and ASP)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am missing something but I can't spot it. Below is the error I receive. Most of the input such as the Ticket no, problem number are from session variables. The only input I type in is the Resolution txtbox. Other fields are optional,

[image: Error received when hitting submit]

Here is my code to insert it where I get my error.

```
 private void InsertResolution()
    {

         Int32 intRetValue;

        intRetValue = clsDatabase.InsertResolution(Convert.ToInt32(chkNoCharge.Checked.ToString()),
            Convert.ToInt32(lblTicketNo.Text.Trim().ToString()), 
            Convert.ToInt32(lblProblemNo.Text.Trim().ToString()), 
            Convert.ToInt32(lblResolutionEnt.Text.Trim().ToString()), 
            txtResolution.Text.Trim(), txtDateFixed.Text.Trim().ToString(), 
            txtDateOnsite.Text.Trim().ToString(), 
            Convert.ToInt32(drpTechnician.SelectedValue), 
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtHours.Text.Trim().ToString()), 
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtCostHours.Text.Trim().ToString()),
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtMileage.Text.Trim().ToString()), 
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtCostMiles.Text.Trim().ToString()),
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtSupplies.Text.Trim().ToString()), 
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtMisc.Text.Trim().ToString()));

        if (intRetValue == 0)
        {
            lblError.Text = "New resolution INSERTED.";
            lblResolutionEnt.Text = (int.Parse(lblResolutionEnt.Text) + 1).ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error inserting new resolution.";
        }
    }
```

Here is my code in my class

```
  public static Int32 InsertResolution(Int32 intNocharge, Int32 intTicketID, Int32 intIncidentNo, Int32 intResNo, String strResDesc, String strDateFix, String strDateOnsite, Int32 intTechID, Decimal decHours, Decimal decCostHours, Decimal decMileage, Decimal decCostMiles, Decimal decSupplies, Decimal decMisc)
    {
        SqlConnection cnSQL;
        SqlCommand cmdSQL;
        Boolean blnErrorOccurred = false; //** set up to false assuming we don't get errors
        Int32 intRetCode = 0;

        cnSQL = AcquireConnection();
        if (cnSQL == null)
        {
            blnErrorOccurred = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //**Build command to execute stored procedure
            cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(); //**opening the SqlCommand
            cmdSQL.Connection = cnSQL; //** opening the command connection 
            cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //** accessing the stored procedure from the command window
            cmdSQL.CommandText = "uspInsertResolution"; //** defining the stored procedure to run


            //**taking the input from the string inputting to the database
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NoCharge", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@NoCharge"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@NoCharge"].Value = intNocharge;


            //***********************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TicketID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@TicketID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@TicketID"].Value = intTicketID;

            //***********************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IncidentNo", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@IncidentNo"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@IncidentNo"].Value = intIncidentNo;

            //***********************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ResNo", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@ResNo"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@ResNo"].Value = intResNo;

            //************************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ResDesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@ResDesc"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters ["@ResDesc"].Value = strResDesc;

            //************************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateFix", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@DateFix"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
          //**if the field is empty or null
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strDateFix))
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@DateFix"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@DateFix"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateFix);
            }

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOnsite", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@DateOnsite"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            //**if the field is empty or null
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strDateOnsite))
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@DateOnsite"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@DateOnsite"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateOnsite);
            }

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TechID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@TechID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@TechID"].Value = intTechID;

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Hours", SqlDbType.Decimal));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@Hours"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@Hours"].Value = decHours;

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Hours", SqlDbType.Decimal));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@Hours"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@Hours"].Value = decHours;

            //********************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mileage", SqlDbType.Decimal));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@Mileage"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            if (decMileage.ToString() == null)
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@Mileage"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@Mileage"].Value = decMileage;
            }

            //*********************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMiles", SqlDbType.Decimal));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@CostMiles"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            if (decCostMiles.ToString() == null)
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@CostMiles"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@CostMiles"].Value = decCostMiles;
            }

            //*********************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Supplies", SqlDbType.Decimal));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@Supplies"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            if (decSupplies.ToString() == null)
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@Supplies"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@Supplies"].Value = decSupplies;
            }

            //*********************************************************************
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Misc", SqlDbType.Decimal));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@Misc"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            if (decMisc.ToString() == null)
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@Misc"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters["@Misc"].Value = decMisc;
            }


            //**return the value and display to the page

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ErrCode", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@ErrCode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            try
            {
                intRetCode = cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                blnErrorOccurred = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Clear();
                cmdSQL.Dispose();
                cnSQL.Close();
                cnSQL.Dispose();
            }
        }

        if (blnErrorOccurred)
        {
            //**if success
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Here is my stored procedure that I call from my class. I appreciate any input.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertResolution]
@TicketID int,
@IncidentNo int,
@ResNo int,
@ResDesc nvarchar(500),
@DateFix datetime,
@DateOnsite datetime,
@TechID int,
@Hours decimal(10,2),
@Mileage decimal(10,1),
@CostMiles money,
@Supplies money,
@Misc money,
@NoCharge int = 0
AS
--*********************************************************************
--** Add a resolution
--*********************************************************************
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ErrCode int;

IF @NoCharge = 1
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Resolutions] ([TicketID],[IncidentNo],[ResolutionNo], 
[ResolutionDesc],[DateFixed],[DateOnsite],[TechnicianID],[Hours], 
[CostHours],[Mileage],[CostMiles],[Supplies],[Misc])
VALUES (@TicketID, @IncidentNo, @ResNo, @ResDesc, @DateFix, @DateOnsite, 
@TechID, @Hours, 0.0, @Mileage, @CostMiles, @Supplies, @Misc)

ELSE
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Resolutions] ([TicketID],[IncidentNo],[ResolutionNo], 
[ResolutionDesc],[DateFixed],[DateOnsite],[TechnicianID],[Hours], 
[CostHours],[Mileage],[CostMiles],[Supplies],[Misc])
SELECT @TicketID, @IncidentNo, @ResNo, @ResDesc, @DateFix, @DateOnsite, 
@TechID, @Hours, [HRate], @Mileage, @CostMiles, @Supplies, @Misc
FROM [dbo].[Technicians]
WHERE [TechnicianID] = @TechID;

SET @ErrCode = @@ERROR;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
RETURN @ErrCode;
```

Comment: Looks that one of the `Convert.To[Something]` is receiving an incorrect value to be converted. Could be a `null` or empty value for an integer, a letter, something that is just not correct. Extract all those `Convert.To...` to variables before running the command, put them into a `try...catch` block and check that :)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but I see you're trying to initialize the (Int32) intRetValue with a bunch of values. In particular the value of a checkbox?!?

Comment: Hi Anderson, thank you for your comment. Yeah something is not converting right.  I will try the try/catch.

Hi nocturns2, yeah my checkbox value is set to 1 when it's checked and 0 if it is unchecked.

Comment: So I found which one was erroring. It was these lines (when I made them variables.

    Decimal decMil = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCostMiles.Text.Trim());
            Decimal decCostMil = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCostMiles.Text.Trim());
            Decimal decSup = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSupplies.Text.Trim());
            Decimal decMisc1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMisc.Text.Trim());
            Int32 intNoch = Convert.ToInt32(chkNoCharge.Checked);
These are supposed to be option and can be left blank and set up validations on these too. When I put value in those fields, those don't error except chbx

Comment: Embedding the type into each variable's name is messy, as is calling `ToString()` on strings.